# MVVM - Using entities in ViewModels

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am really just starting out with MVVM, IoC and Dependency Injection and I've hit a stumbling block that I don't know how to solve but I do understand why it's happening.

I am using Castle Windsor for DI and IoC functionality and MVVM Light as my MVVM framework in a WPF application.  Using [this tutorial](http://fir3pho3nixx.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/silverlight-mvvm-light-toolkit-and.html) I have managed to get Castle Windsor to create a `MainPageViewModel` that has a `IGroupRepository` injected into the constructor.  I have registered a mock implementation of this in Castle Windsor.

The following is the only other code in the `MainPageViewModel` class besides the constructor.

```
public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> Groups
{
    get
    {
        var groupVms = new ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>();
        IEnumerable<Group> groups = _repository.GetAllGroups();
        foreach (Group g in groups)
        {
            var vm = new GroupViewModel(g);
            groupVms.Add(vm);
        }

        return groupVms;
    }
}
```

The intention is to create a view model for each of the groups in the repository.  However, doing this causes Castle Windsor to give the following exception:

> Can't create component 'Planner.ViewModel.GroupViewModel' as it has dependencies 
>       to be satisfied.
>   'Planner.ViewModel.GroupViewModel' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>
> - Service 'Planner.Models.Group' which was not registered.

I understand this exception - Castle Windsor is responsible for constructing my view models but it has no way of handling my entity.

I have done plenty of Googling but have found very few answers or suggestions to this problem which makes me think that what I am doing is wrong.  [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720329/should-i-use-dtos-as-my-data-models-in-mvvm) has two answers which suggest that having an entity on the view model is ok but I'm beginning to wonder if that's true.  Other questions, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147250/ef4-mvvm-expose-entities-in-viewmodel) suggest that the entity should be nowhere near the view model.

What is the correct way to resolve this problem?

**Update:** As requested, this is the stacktrace for the exception:

```
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.AssertNotWaitingForDependency()
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments)
at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve(Type service)
at Planner.ViewModel.ViewModelResolver.Resolve(String viewModelName) in D:\Planner\Planner\Planner\ViewModel\ViewModelResolver.cs:line 27
at Planner.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator.get_Item(String viewModelName) in D:\Planner\Planner\Planner\ViewModel\ViewModelLocator.cs:line 21
```

I thought that this was the correct behaviour because of the following code which (I believe) intercepts any calls to the constructor of a view model and injects them as appropriate.

```
public class ViewModelResolver : IViewModelResolver
{
    private IWindsorContainer _container;

    public object Resolve(string viewModelName)
    {
        if (_container == null)
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer();
            _container.Install(new WindsorViewsInstaller());
            _container.Install(new WindsorRepositoriesInstaller());
        }

        var viewModelType =
            GetType()
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.Name.Equals(viewModelName))
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return _container.Resolve(viewModelType);
    }
}
```

**Update 2:** I think this answers Ritch's query:

```
public class ViewModelLocator : DynamicObject
{
    public IViewModelResolver Resolver { get; set; }

    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        Resolver = new ViewModelResolver();
    }

    public object this[string viewModelName]
    {
        get
        {
            return Resolver.Resolve(viewModelName);
        }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = this[binder.Name];
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think I understand this a little more now.  The problem isn't actually with the original code I posted.  The problem is occurring actually setting up Windsor isn't it?  I'm still not sure how I solve that problem though.

Comment: Reading through your sample, I don't see where you're asking Castle Windsor to create a GroupViewModel.  In the sample code, you're calling the constructor directly, which would not involve Castle Windsor.  Can you show the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: How does the container bind to the GroupViewModels you are creating?

Comment: @RitchMelton I have updated the question with the code that I think answers your question.  I've also updated it with some new insight I've had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ritch's answer led me in the right direction but I wanted to post a separate answer so that I can show the code that I ended up with in the hope that it will be useful to the next person trying to do this.

As well as Ritch's answer, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053092/using-castle-windsor-child-containers-to-resolve-a-type-with-a-specific-instance) and [this blog post](http://kozmic.pl/2009/12/23/castle-typed-factory-facility-reborn/) by one of the main contributers to Castle Windsor, Krzysztof Koźmic, all helped me to solve this problem in what I believe is the correct way.

As Ritch said, I shouldn't have been calling the constructor for my view model directly - that is what the container is there for.  So the way to do it is to create a class which will help Windsor to create your view model.  This is known as a typed factory facility.  The good thing about these classes is that you don't actually need to implement them - they are just interfaces.  This is the code for the class that will eventually be used to create the view model:

```
public interface IGroupViewModelFactory
{
    GroupViewModel Create(Group group);
}
```

This is injected into the constructor for the view model that will create the `GroupViewModel` which in my case was the `MainWindowViewModel` class.  Here is the code for that class:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IGroupRepository _repository;
    private readonly IGroupViewModelFactory _groupViewModelFactory;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IGroupRepository repository, IGroupViewModelFactory groupViewModelFactory)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _groupViewModelFactory = groupViewModelFactory;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> Groups
    {
        get
        {
            var groupVms = new ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>();
            IEnumerable<Group> groups = _repository.GetAllGroups();
            foreach (Group g in groups)
            {
                var vm = _groupViewModelFactory.Create(g);
                groupVms.Add(vm);
            }

            return groupVms;
        }
    }
}
```

The final step is to register the factory class with Windsor and that is done by this piece of code:

```
_container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

_container.Register(
    Component.For<Group>(),
    Component.For<IGroupViewModelFactory>()
    .AsFactory());
```

It's worth noting that the question I linked to earlier did not have the `Component.For<Group>(),` line in the above piece of code.  Without that I was getting an exception from Windsor but unfortunately I didn't keep the details and I can no longer replicate it so there was probably something else amiss in my application.

Through the magic of Castle Windsor, you can now create view models from entities in a repository!

Answer (score 1):

The property `Groups` on `MainPageViewModel` creates a bunch of VMs that aren't in the container, but your stacktrace is the Locator looking to bind/create an instance of the GroupViewModel (Why? I cannot tell at this point with the code you've posted.).

You have a disconnect in how the `GroupViewModel`s are created and what the container is doing. You either need to let Windsor create these through a factory interface [Factory Interface Documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) or remove them from the container entirely and manage them yourself. Based on gut feeling, I would lean towards the factory interface.